# How to combine data from one table where there are duplicate values into a single row?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have tried what i thought was a pretty simple sql with php to do the following but it is not turning out correctly and i cant find a good way to "google" the solutions. I have a table valoreguide2 that holds over 200,000 records with multiple columns in this table are duplicate rows that have different values in some columns but same value in other columns. I want to take all of the values and put them in a new table, while doing this i want to combine the rows that have the same value in the column labeled isbn and keep all of the values for those rows in one row in the new table.

> example is
>   [image: picture of table]

if you cant see the image it is a table with 20 columns including a auto increment field. I would like to take all of the information from this table and insert it into another table with different column titles but combine them based on isbn.  the code i have written is a follows:

```
`$results = $conn->query("select * from valoreguide2 group by isbn");
while ($row12 = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
$isbn = $row12['isbn'];
$APrice =$row12['Acomm'];
$AQty=$row12['Aqty'];
$IPrice =$row12['Icomm'];
$IQty=$row12['Iqty'];
$SPrice =$row12['Scomm'];
$SQty=$row12['Sqty'];
$TPrice =$row12['Tcomm'];
$TQty=$row12['Tqty'];
$NPrice =$row12['Ncomm'];
$NQty=$row12['Nqty'];
$BBPrice =$row12['BBcomm'];
$BBQty=$row12['BBqty'];  



$guide_prices = array('amtext'=>(float)($APrice), 'ingram'=>(float)($IPrice), 'sterling'=>(float)($SPrice), 'tichenor'=>(float)($TPrice), 'nebraska'=>(float)($NPrice), 'BB'=>(float)($BBPrice), );

$bestGuidePrice = max($guide_prices);
$bestGuidePrice = number_format($bestGuidePrice,2,'.','');

foreach ($guide_prices as $key => $val) {
if ($val == max($guide_prices))
{
    $bestGuide = $key;
}

  }

 $valoreprice=(($bestGuidePrice/1.15)-5);

$conn->query("insert into valorebest2 (isbn, aprice, iprice, sprice, tprice, nprice, bookbyte, bestprice, valore, bestguide) values ('$isbn','$APrice','$IPrice','$SPrice','$TPrice','$NPrice','$BBPrice','$bestGuidePrice','$valoreprice','$bestGuide') ");
}`
```

but the result is not combining the rows it is just picking one.. If i have not provided enough please let me know.. i did not want to type on and on when someone is going to say hey you missed a comma.

Edited:

Using MySQL

Edited: This is the output i am looking for
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you be specific about the database, you use: Oracle, MS SQL, MySql ..?

Here is an answer that it based on ansi SQL. Hope it helps

Testdata.
`CREATE TABLE tbs_test (ID, ISBN, A, B, C, D) AS
SELECT 1,'0001','A','B','C',10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2,'0002','A',null,null,null FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3,'0002',null,'B',null,null FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4,'0002',null,null,'C',null FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5,'0003','A',null,'C',10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6,'0003',null,null,null,10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 7,'0004',null,null,'C',10 FROM DUAL;`

This select groups by isbn, taking the min-value of each column, that resides in a row with the same isbn.
`select isbn, min(A), min(B), min(C), min(D)
from tbs_test
group by isbn
order by isbn;`

This select groups by isbn, takes min-value of A,B,C and sums D
`select isbn, min(A), min(B), min(C), sum(D)
from tbs_test
group by isbn
order by isbn;`

Hope this helps :-)

Comment: I think MySQL will accept my suggestion, while it is ANSI sql :-)  My suggestion doesn't handle the insert part. Let me know if you don't know how to let an insert take input from a select

Comment: This is not quite what i am looking for... i dont want to take min or make values. each row has null in every column but three that are all related to the same table that they are pulled from (etc table A,I,S,BB....) instead if  having a table like above i have a table that looks like the second picture in my edited question...The id column will be a self generating number counter in the new file so no need to bring over.

Comment: Hi Hasan. If you use either min or max function (doesn't matter which of them), I think you'll get exactly what you showed in the second picture. Null values have no influence for min / max. Fx: The first isbn (...004) appears in 5 rows. In one row Aprice is 9, in the other 4 rows Aprice is null. Min() of Aprice is then 9. Volia.... or...?

Comment: Ok i understand what you are saying now.. but i want to insert it into a table that already exist --i will be using a cron job to run this everyday... also sometimes their will be 1 row sometimes 2 all the way to 6 that have the same isbn does this make a difference. Probably should have mentioned that i am using PHP to do this.

Comment: this does not work it will not let me select from the table

Comment: The insert-based-on-a-select construction would match your scenario perfect, I think. Perhaps you'll need to make an additional **update**-based-on-a-select (if the isbn already exists in your output table). Then you'd need to extend my sample-code with an if-exists-clause. In case of not exist: fire a insert. In case of exist: fire a update.

Answer (score 0):

If it wont let you select, how on earth can you get any values to work with? :-)

It you'll succeed in getting acces to the data, this would do it (notice: the fake_time column is just a way to emulate two different situations in the input table. You can remove it from the select/update if you'll go live with the code):

```
CREATE TABLE tbs_test_input (ID, ISBN, A, B, C, D, Fake_time) AS
SELECT  1,'0001','A','B','C',10,1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  2,'0002','A',null,null,null,1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  3,'0002',null,'B',null,null,1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  4,'0002',null,null,'C',null,1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  5,'0003','A',null,'C',10,1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  6,'0003',null,null,null,10,1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  7,'0004',null,null,'C',10,1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  8,'0003',null,'B',null,null,2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  9,'0003',null,'B',null,20,2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 10,'0004','A',null,null,null,2 FROM DUAL
;

create table tbs_test_output as select ISBN, A, B, C, D
```

from tbs_test_input where 1=2;

```
insert into tbs_test_output
select isbn, min(A), min(B), min(C), min(D)
  from tbs_test_input 
 where isbn not in (select isbn from tbs_test_output)
   and fake_time = 1
group by isbn
order by isbn;

select * from tbs_test_output;

update tbs_test_output o
set (A,B,C,D) = (
select min(i.A), min(i.B), min(i.C), min(i.D)
  from tbs_test_input i
  where i.fake_time = 2
 group by i.isbn
 having i.isbn = o.isbn
)
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
      FROM tbs_test_input i
     WHERE i.isbn = o.isbn 
       and i.fake_time = 2)
;

select * from tbs_test_output;
```

The result:

4 rows inserted.

`ISBN A B C          D
\---- - - - ---------- 
0001 A B C         10
0002 A B C
0003 A   C         10
0004     C         10`

2 rows updated.

`ISBN A B C          D
\---- - - - ----------
0001 A B C         10
0002 A B C
0003   B           20
0004 A`